# How to implement the order analysis in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have an audio file that represents the sound of a motor. I've been reading that the 'normal' fft doesn't deliver a valuable analysis about the machine, and that I should use the **Order analysis** to describe the  'behavior' of the machine. I recorded its sound while incrementing its speed, and I put the records together and calculated its spectogram. Here is the code for that:

```
%% read the Audio file and plot its 
clear, clc , clf;
M = 512;
k =1 
data= 0 ;
   for i =100:5:180
    fileName =['A10_uSp0_Mic100k_2nd_V_',int2str(i),'.wav']
    [x(:,k),Fs] = audioread(fileName);
    k = k+1 ;
end
for i = 1:length(x(1,:))
    data = [data(:);x(:,i)];
end
 k = length(x(1,:));
    while k ~= 2
   data = [data(:);x(:,k)];
   k = k -1;
    end
spectrogram(data,hamming(M),M/2,0:20:4000,Fs,'yaxis');
```

and the result looks like:

[image: Spectogram]

As you might be able to see, I incremented the speed of the machine by 5 for each timepoint.  My question is how to calculate the order analysis for this system!?
Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: To perform order analysis you generally need to know the rotational speed of the machine. Do you have a tachometer or a one-per-revolution sensor on the motor that you can record at the same time as the vibration signal?

Comment: No I don't have it, I'm only allowed to listen to the machine

Comment: Do you control the speed during measurement, or do you have to just take what you get? How stable is the speed

Comment: well I can control it , let's say if I know the min and the max speed I can measure the generated sound from min to max rpm !

Comment: If you want more help from Matlab users, it would help a lot if you could actually say specifically what you want to calculate. Then we can help you with how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a scientific question than a question about programming. Order analysis can be done using the fourier transform. All you need to do is looking for **diagonal lines in the output**, i.e. where the frequency of the noise is proportional to the rotation speed.

In your example image there is such an order from 2000 Hz at time(speed) 0 to 4000 Hz at time(speed) 150. Afterwards it seems to reflected downwards, probably an artifact of insufficient sampling.

So which order is it? For this you need to know the rotational speed of the motor which you do not seem to know. There is also another weaker order starting at 3000 Hz at time(speed) 0. With two or more visible orders you might be able to deduce the rotational speed of the motor (by requiring the frequencies to be whole number multiples of the original speed).

Anyway the code probably doesn't need to be changed except for a higher frequency resolution.

Comment: first thanks for your answer, but what do you mean with deducing the rotational speed of the motor , how you'll do that in question example ?

Comment: The idea is that the noise frequency is proportional to the rotational speed of the motor. For a single diagonal line you don't know: could be twice, could be five times the rotational speed of the motor. But it's a whole integer number. However for two or more diagonal lines you get a number of equations that you can solve assuming integer numbers for the proportionality factors.

Comment: @Engine I was interested in your issue and that is why I placed a bounty. Now, as pointed by some, the question is more about signal processing than coding, consider posting it to the dsp site, or the physics site with the 'acoustics' tag.

Comment: @Jigg thanks a lot , I 've posted the questionon the dsp , it didn't bring anything, thanks again !

Comment: @Trilarion  I still can't understand how may I get the rpm or the state of machine based on the lines I see in the spectogram , would you please pput an example ?

Comment: Thanks for your input, it should put OP on the right rails.